# bootstrap-datepicker-rails options not applied

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using `rails-bootstrap-datepicker` (latest version of date) to implement a datepicker, but while the calendar is rendering and working as it should, the options I've specified are not applied apart from the `format` attribute.

I've tried render the form and the options using a helper:

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :submission, local: true do |form| %>

  <div class="datepicker">
    <%= form.label :dates %>
    <%= datepicker(form, :dates) %>
  </div>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

application_helper.rb

```
  def datepicker(form, field)
    form.text_field(field, data: { provide: "datepicker", 
    'date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
    'weekStart': 1, 
    'maxViewMode': 2, 
    'multidate': true, 
    'daysOfWeekHighlighted': "0,6", 
    'calendarWeeks': true }).html_safe
  end
```

As well as using jquery:

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :submission, local: true do |form| %>

  <div class="datepicker" data-provide='datepicker'>
    <%= form.label :dates %>
  </div>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<script>
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
   format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
   weekStart: 1,
   maxViewMode: 2,
   multidate: true,
   daysOfWeekHighlighted: "0,6",
   calendarWeeks: true
 });
</script>
```

But as far as I can see, I only get the default options of the picker and not the ones I've specified apart from `format`. I've also verified that `jquery` is actually loaded and running, so that shouldn't be the issue.

In my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

In my application.css:

```
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

I'm not seeing any errors in my browser console.

The related lines from my Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'

gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.1'

gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here in case someone else comes across it.

If using a helper, all options must be prefixed by `date-` else they won't work. That's the reason why only the `date-format` worked for me. I believed that property was named as such and that the prefix didn't apply to the rest of the options. So, a working version of the specified options within an helper would look like this, in my case:

```
def datepicker(form, field)
    form.text_field(field, data: { provide: "datepicker", 
    'date-format': 'dd/mm/yyyy', 
    'date-weekStart': 1, 
    'date-maxViewMode': 2, 
    'date-multidate': true, 
    'date-daysOfWeekHighlighted': "0,6", 
    'date-calendarWeeks': true }).html_safe
end
```